# identical results for fixed and random network meta analysis

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I performed a network meta-analysis in r package netmeta using the netmeta function and the results are identical for the fixed and random effects analyses. Is this possible or did I do something wrong? I'm not too strong on the theory part, but I thought that at least the confidence intervals should be different between the two...?

Comment: It is possible, occasionally. It might also be due to a star-shaped evidence network without closed loops.

Comment: You could try asking on https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// where the authors of neameta sometimes hang out.